# How to monitor 2 or 3 table data change with SqlDependency

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sqldependency

this way we monitor table data change by sql dependency.

```
private static void RegisterNotification()
        {
            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
                    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT ID, Name FROM dbo.TestTable";
                    dep = new SqlDependency(cmd);
                    dep.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(OnDataChange);
                    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    {
                        while (dr.Read())
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Name = " + dr[1].ToString());
                        }
                    }
                    dr.Close();
                    Console.WriteLine("Waiting for any data changes...\nPress to end program.");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                //SqlDependency.Stop(connStr);
            }

        }
```

this way we specify sql `SELECT ID, Name FROM dbo.TestTable` for table change. i like to know if i need to monitor 2 table then we can write sql like this way

```
SELECT ID, Name FROM dbo.TestTable1;SELECT ID, Name FROM dbo.TestTable2
```

and read table data like this way

```
SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
{
     while (dr.Read())
     {
        Console.WriteLine("Name = " + dr[1].ToString());
     }
 }
```

and then again `dr.NextResult()` and read again

```
 while (dr.Read())
         {
            Console.WriteLine("Name = " + dr[1].ToString());
         }
```

if i am going to wrong direction to monitor multiple table data change then please guide me with right info.looking for suggestion. thanks

Answer (score 4):

Here very nice article with source code

SQL Cache Dependency with SQL Server, LINQ and ASP.NET 3.5
http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=263

Important (from the article )

```
GRANT SUBSCRIBE QUERY NOTIFICATIONS TO "TESTSERVER\ASPNET"
```

C#

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
SqlDependency.Start(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["pubsConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
}
```

The following code also stops the listener:

```
protected void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
SqlDependency.Stop(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["pubsConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
}
```

Comment: probably u do not understand my requirement. suppose if i have 3 table which has no relation in each other then how could i monitor those 3 table data change using sql dependency ? if u know then come with solution. thanks

Comment: you can use this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.aggregatecachedependency.aspx  The AggregateCacheDependency class monitors a collection of dependency objects so that when any of them change, the cached item is automatically removed. The objects in the array can be CacheDependency objects, SqlCacheDependency objects, custom objects derived from CacheDependency, or any combination of these.